# Postfix: Gmail marking my email as spam

Tags: postfix, spam, gmail

I'm been trying to understand why Gmail is treating the email sent from one of my domain/server as SPAM. I found a lot of threads here about this issue, however I checked the usual suspects like domain keys, spf etc.

My email is accepted by Outlook.com, which from my understanding has a lot more aggressive spam filter.

I tested my config using `auth-results@verifier.port25.com` and I got this:

```
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

Everything looks fine.

After sending an email to a gmail account I get this under the headers:

```
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@mydomain.org designates 89.x.x.8 as permitted sender) client-ip=89.x.x.x;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@mydomain.org designates 89.x.x.8 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=user@mydomain.org;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.org
```

As you can see, the email is passing on `spf` and `dkim` without issues on gmail servers.

Finally I checked my server IP, hostname and domain at `http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx` for RBL blocks and they're not listed anywhere.

Why is gmail treating my emails as SPAM? It makes no sense, I've complied with every single good practice.

Other Note:

- Reverse DNS is also ok;
- Tests at `http://www.allaboutspam.com` are green except for `Email server is not using BATV format`;

Thank you.

---

Comment: TCB13 - I know this might be too obvious, but what is the content of the emails you're sending like?  Have you run them through spam checks?

Comment: What is the message that Gmail displayed at the top of the message, describing why it was marked as spam?

Comment: @MichaelHampton "Why is this message in Spam? It's similar to messages that were detected by our spam filters.  Learn more" and they send me to this link https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en&ctx=mail&expand=5.

Comment: @DaveHolland I've tried multiple contents, HTML and plain text, all result on the same issue. The last one was "This is another email test, please ignore."

Comment: TCB13 - Most of the time it comes down to content... unless your specific domain has had a lot of spam complaints in the past.  Is this a new domain that you're just starting to mail from, or no?

Comment: @DaveHolland It's a domain I own for some year, but I didn't use it to send email before. Does spoofed emails account as "spam complaints in the past". I guess all domain suffer from that.

Comment: @TCB - Many domains suffer from that, however that's why we have things like SPF records and domain keys.  Have you tried sending through a totally benign email - devoid of words like "test"?  A normal subject and body as though you were just writing an email to a friend?

Comment: @DaveHolland yep I tried that and they always get into SPAM. I'm very annoying with google because of this. Hotmail can receive without being marked as spam.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently after a few days it start working fine.

Right now, I guess what really matters in GMAIL is actually passing this tests:

```
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

And wait 3 or 4 days so google can update their servers. Seems like the spam filter does some kind of internal cache on `DKIM` and `SPF` lookups for a particular domain.

---

UPDATE: This problem seems to be back, I've no ideia how to fix it.

Comment: Unless you send a lot of e-mail from your server, slowly ramp up the sending from it, and get a lot of people to mark it as "not spam", then you will always hit this issue. This has to do with the magical black box that Google/Microsoft use to filter e-mail. There's more about it here: https://penguindreams.org/blog/how-google-and-microsoft-made-email-unreliable/