# SFP + Gmail = Emails delivered to spam box

Tags: spam, spf, gmail

A long time ago I posted a question here: [Postfix: Gmail marking my email as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/606150/postfix-gmail-marking-my-email-as-spam) where I said that although emails send from my servers were passing all the DKIM and SPF tests they were getting deliver to SPAM on Gmail.

Two days ago I was configuring a new system and noticed a very strange thing related to SPF — **without any SPF** TXT record on the DNS Zone, the **email are delivered to Inbox** and **with SPF defined the are getting delivered on SPAM**.

My SPF entries are like this:

```
domain.dev.             IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x ip6:x:x:x:x::x -all"
```

Isn't SPF record for the domain correct? If not what is wrong?

Every time I place that line on my DNS zone, Google starts delivering my email to SPAM, and even more interesting is what Gmail says about the emails.

Test email **sent with SPF**:

```
spf=pass (google.com: domain of email@domain.dev designates x.x.x.x as permitted sender) smtp.mail=email@domain.dev;
```

=> Delivered to SPAM box.

Test Email **sent without SPF**:

```
spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of email@domain.dev designates x.x.x.x as permitted sender) smtp.mail=email@domain.dev;
```

=> Delivered to inbox.

Anyway has experienced this before? Is my SPF wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Considering that it seems to consider both to have passed the SPF check, it would make more sense if the different actions came down to something else than SPF (email contents, maybe?).

Comment: I tried the same content and then a different content again in both test, to avoid that. I know it doesn't make a lot of sense, but I've been around this issue for months now.

Comment: HOw did you derive the IP4 and IP6 entries for this SPF record? Who are you sending email "from?" Headers would be super helpful or at least a few more details. I think the most likely explanation is that you entering incorrect IP addresses in your SPF. If you corrected them, that'd fix the problem.

Comment: @NeilAnuskiewicz the IP is correct, also just look at this `spf=pass` is there was an issue with the IP it would not mark it as `pass`.

Comment: Just to confirm, does your SPF record pass a validation check?
http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

Comment: @NeilAnuskiewicz yes it does! `SPF record passed validation test with pySPF (Python SPF library)!`